# Combining NOT with other queries in Chef search returns no results?

Tags: chef

I'm having some very strange issues with Chef search. I want to find instances that have failed to bootstrap properly, and I'm using two methods to detect this: instances in the default environment `_default`, and instances missing a role that I apply to *all* managed instances, `role[base]`. Right now I have one failed instance which is not in `role[base]`:

```
$ knife search "NOT role:base"
1 items found
```

So there's definitely a node matching one of my criteria. But if I try to find instances that match *either* of my criteria, it doesn't work - I get no results:

```
$ knife search "environment:_default OR NOT role:base"
0 items found

$ knife search "(environment:_default OR NOT role:base)"
0 items found

$ knife search "(environment:_default) OR (NOT role:base)"
0 items found
```

OK, [the manual says](https://docs.chef.io/chef_search.html#operators) there might be issues combining `AND` and `NOT`, so maybe there's also an issue with `OR`?

```
$ knife search "(environment:_default OR -role:base)"
0 items found
```

Nope. Maybe it's the order?

```
$ knife search "(NOT role:base OR environment:_default)"
ERROR: knife search failed: invalid search query: '(NOT role:base OR environment:_default)'

$ knife search "NOT role:base OR environment:_default"
ERROR: knife search failed: invalid search query: 'NOT role:base OR environment:_default'
```

No luck. How can I search for instances that are missing a particular role, or are in a particular environment? Am I stuck with doing two separate searches and combining results?

Comment: That should `chef_environment`. Also negative queries don’t usually work the way you think because of all the data massaging we do

Comment: @coderanger it doesn't work with `chef_environment` either, I noticed that error after I posted the question. Can you elaborate on "negative queries don't usually work the way you think"? I assumed they worked as indicated in the documentation. How do they in fact work?